# Concatenating cells (DD MM YYYY) in multiple rows

Tags: excel, date, format, concatenation

I understand how to concatenate individual cells to show a date format. How do I do this for 24K rows in a spreadsheet without having to copy and paste the CONCATENATE term in each row manually?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If your are on Excel 365 you simply put the whole column into the formula - it will spill down:
`=DATE(C2:C24333,B2:B24333,A2:A24333)`

Where year is in column C, month in column B and day in column A

Or you use a table (Insert > table or Ctrl + T) - then the formula is filled down automatically.